# Platform for User Created Content

Tags: content-management-system, pyrocms

I'm working on a new project where I'd like users to be able to add content.  The site is a project collaboration site where users can, sign up and create a profile, post a project idea (give it a name, some details and upload a couple of pictures, etc.), and hit a create button.  The project would then be featured as a thumbnail on a Projects page where others could comment on the project and review the submitted idea.

Would a CMS be suitable for an application such as this?  The user content would be added on the front end, so users wouldn't necessarily be able to access the control panel to add content so I'm not sure if a CMS would work or not.

I was taking a look at PyroCMS as I have some familiarity with PHP and CI but I don't know if this would fit the bill.

Any thoughts?  Thank you!

Comment: That is possible as a module in PyroCMS and you may benefit a lot from PyroCMS backend or features like events and plugins which will save your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is absolutely doable with Pyro CMS Pro or by adding on the Streams extension. That would allow you to create the front-facing pages without any programming. You can create any number of custom fields to allow this.

Comment: this dosent add any more value than Jahandideh AR's comment. Try adding more information.

Comment: I was specific about the extension needed, something that may have helped steer him. Also, not knowing his proficiency level, the fact no programming is needed may have been a benefit.